# javascript - counting objects

Tags: javascript, jquery, count

I have a javascript object that contains 6 objects that may contain additional arrays or objects.  Using javascript or jquery, how can I quickly count number of these 6 top level objects

```
1   Object { salesman="1714, name="Lucien Layton", events={...}}
2   Object { salesman="1715", name="Hugo Hayne", events={...}}
3   Object { salesman="17165", name="Jonas Jessie", events={...}}
4   Object { salesman="1718", name="Ezequiel Ebner", events={...}}
5   Object { salesman="1721", name="Randolph Rodda", events={...}}
6   Object { salesman="1722", name="Edwin Earles", events={...}}
```

Comment: If you don't need support to older browsers you can use `Object.keys(yourObj).length`, otherwise a simple `for..in` loop should be enough

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could do this...

```
var objectsLength = 0;
for ({}[++objectsLength] in objects) {}
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bPBet/).

It's kind of funky, but also cool. Still, due to its unusualness, I'd just suggest the more common method...

```
var objectsLength = 0;
for (var prop in objects) {
    objectsLength++;
}
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9gTrT/).

If you're unsure about your environment and think they're might be iterable properties on the prototype chain, use `hasOwnProperty()` (or create your objects with `Object.create(null)`).

If browser support is in your favour...

```
var objectsLength = Object.keys(objects).length;
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/EnRbW/).

Comment: Interesting solution. Just keep in mind the numeric keys will be enumerated if you have to iterate the properties again for some reason.

Comment: Even more interesting: after the `for..in` loop, an object like `{foo: 1, bar: 2, baz: 3}` becomes `{1: "foo", 2: "bar", 3: "baz", foo: 1, bar: 2, baz: 3}` - but nothing on that code says the values of the new numeric keys should be the original keys!

Comment: It happens with every type of object, this is very strange! For example an object `{a: "b", c: "d"}` becomes `{1: "a", 2: "c", a: "b", c: "d"}`.

Comment: The cause seems to be: in `for prop in obj`, `prop` is assigned the key name. So `objects[++objectsLength]` in that position actually means `objects[++objectsLength] = keyname`. I never saw that in js before, very interesting behavior! I will try to dig deeper.

Comment: @bfavaretto The placement does. The left side expression is always set to the key name by [*Call PutValue(lhsRef, P)*](http://es5.github.io/#x12.6.4), apparently whether it's a single variable or uses a member operator.

Comment: @JonathanLonowski Just realized that, thanks for pointing it out in the language spec.

Comment: So in summary: the first method can't be used safely, since it manipulates the original object and will give different results when applied multiple times.

Comment: Definitely that would be a problem. I *fixed* it, but by this stage it's so weird I'd just recommend one of the latter two solutions.

Comment: @Alex—an interesting quirk, but likely very inefficient as a new object will be created every time the LHS expression is evaludated (once for every enumerable property of *objects*). Also, there should be a *hasOwnProperty* test before the counter is incremented (guessing that the OP doesn't want to count inherited enumerable properties).

Comment: @RobG Yeah, I put it in the _interesting-but-wouldn't-use_ bucket. OP can use `hasOwnProperty()` if they're unsure about their environment.